# restrict posts per page

Tags: wp-query

I want to display in a *featured slideshow* only 3 posts, but it is ignored and it shows a lot of posts. How to fix it?

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 3, 
        'post_id' => $featitem 
    )
);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    $my_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

`post_id` is not a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) parameter. Perhaps you meant `post__in`? If so then `$featitem` needs to be an array of post IDs.